# how to check if webelements are in order?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using the code below, i am trying to open a link page and then go to mobile section and sort the items on the basis of name order. now i want to check if the mobile devices are sorted by Name means alphabetically.
i tried to convert my List below to arraylist but not able to check if elements printed are in ascending order, kindly help

```
package selflearning;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Guru99Ecommerce1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://live.guru99.com/index.php/");

        String title=driver.getTitle();
        String expectedTitle = "Home page";
        System.out.println("The title of the webPage is " + title);
        expectedTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(title);
        System.out.println("Title is verified");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Mobile']")).click();

        String nextTitle = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println("The title of next page" + nextTitle);

        String nextExpectedTitle = "pageMobile";
        nextExpectedTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(nextTitle);
        System.out.println("The next title is verified");

        Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='category-products']//div/div[@class='sorter']/div/select[@title='Sort By']")));
        s.selectByVisibleText("Name");

        List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='product-info']/h2/a"));

        for(WebElement e: element)
        {
            String str = e.getText();
            System.out.println("The items are  " + str);
        }
        HashSet<WebElement> value = new 
        List<WebElement> list = new ArrayList<WebElement>(element);
        list.addAll(element);
        System.out.println("arrangement" + list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some examples showcasing what you want to achieve? How does the list currently look like? For checking if a list is sorted you can just traverse it and check if an element is correctly greater than or equal (with respect to the given order) the previous element. Or you could sort it and check if the resulting list is equals to the input list (does only work if there are no equal elements as they might change order).

Comment: In one of your last lines there is some code missing: `HashSet<WebElement> value = new `.

Comment: i was trying to do hashset but couldnt achieve,

Comment: as per my code, i am able to print the elements tilll for each loop

Comment: Example : lets say i have 3 items to be displayed : iphone, huawei,samsung ,  now all i wanted to check if displayed elements are in alphabetic order only.

Comment: Yeah, sort the list with `Collections.sort(myList)` and then compare the result to the list before the sorting with `equals`. Or traverse the list and compare each element with the next/previous, by using `compareTo`. Note that `String#compareTo` compares lexicographically, which is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to just grab the list of products, loop through them, and see if the current product name (a `String`) is "greater" than the last product name using [`String#compareToIgnoreCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)).

I would write some functions for the common tasks you are likely to repeat for this page.

```
public static void sortBy(String sortValue)
{
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[title='Sort By']"))).selectByVisibleText(sortValue);
}

public static List<String> getProductNames()
{
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    List<WebElement> products = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.products-grid h2.product-name"));
    for (WebElement product : products)
    {
        names.add(product.getText());
    }

    return names;
}

public static boolean isListSorted(List<String> list)
{
    String last = list.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        String current = list.get(i);
        if (last.compareToIgnoreCase(current) > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        last = current;
    }

    return true;
}
```

NOTE: You should be using JUnit or TestNG for your assertions instead of writing your own because it makes it much, much easier (and you don't have to write and debug your own which saves time). The code I wrote below is using TestNG. You can see how much shorter (and simpler) the code below is when using a library like TestNG.

```
String url = "http://live.guru99.com/index.php";
driver.navigate().to(url);

Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "Home page");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//nav[@id='nav']//a[.='Mobile']")).click();
Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "Mobile");
sortBy("Name");
System.out.println(getProductNames());
System.out.println(isListSorted(getProductNames()));
```

Where `getProductNames()` returns

```
[IPHONE, SAMSUNG GALAXY, SONY XPERIA]
```

Comment: @JainishKapadia The code for `getProductNames()` is above. I don't understand what you are asking.